# Lightning Web Components: How to handle events from grand child on the owner(eventParent) component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I have 3 Lightning web components, Parent ->Child -> Grand child all with just a lightning button inside it.

**eventParent:**

```
<template>
<lightning-button
variant="brand"
label="Submitparent"
onclick={handleClick}>
</lightning-button> 
<c-event-child></c-event-child>
</template>
```

**javascript file**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class EventParent extends LightningElement {    
    handleClick() {
        alert('alert from parent');
    }
    handleNotify(){
        alert("received event from grand child even though i am the parent");
    }
}
```

**eventChild:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-button
    variant="brand"
    label="Submitchild"
    onclick={handleClick}>
    </lightning-button> 
    <div onnotify={handleNotify1}>
    <c-eventgrandchild onnotify={handleNotify}></c-eventgrandchild>
</div>
    </template>
```

**Javascript file:**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class EventChild extends LightningElement {
    handleClick() {
        alert('alert from child');
    }
    handleNotify(){
        alert("received event from grand child");
    }
    handleNotify1(){
        alert("received event from grand child through bubble"); 
    }
}
```

**eventgrandchild:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-button
    variant="brand"
    label="Submitgrandchild"
    onclick={handleClick}>
    </lightning-button>    
</template>
```

Javascript file:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Eventgrandchild extends LightningElement {
    handleClick() {
        alert('alert from grand child1');
        this.dispatchEvent(
            // Default values for bubbles and composed are false.
            new CustomEvent('notify',{ bubbles: true })
        );
    }
}
```

**Question:**

1. What is the correct way to fire an event from grand child which my owner(in this case eventParent) needs to receive and react accordingly?
2. According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_propagation) they say use capture and bubbles false which is the most recommended,if i use that the event will never reach the parent. Are we expected to catch this event in event child component and fire an event again which will be handled by the parent component?
   Just trying to understand the best practices around events.

**Update based on Jayant's Answer:**
Based on documentation from salesforce it seems the way to do it is to pass the event upward in the hierarchy

> **Events Up, Properties Down**
>
> In a complex component (one that contains several parent and child
>   components) we recommend you propagate the event up through the
>   component hierarchy, so parent components can respond to child events.
>   If you have other child components (not the one firing the event) you
>   can pass a property down to those children in response to the event.

If i have 4 or 5 level hierarchy i need to fire 4 events to reach the top which seems a bit of overkill. Is this the only way to do it or can we use capture and bubbles true and push the event up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a good example of this topic on [Handle Events in Lightning Web Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/handle-events-in-lightning-web-components) trailhead which discusses the same use case as you have here (and answers both your questions).

The idea is to *chain* the events up the hierarchy. So basically you will need to handle the event being propagated in every component and then pass it on up in the hierarhcy.

Below excerpt and the image from the linked trailhead module describes this in detail :

> **Events Up, Properties Down**
>
> In a complex component (one that contains several parent and child components) we recommend you propagate the event up through the component hierarchy, so parent components can respond to child events. If you have other child components (not the one firing the event) you can pass a property down to those children in response to the event.

[image: Image Courtesy: Trailhead]

(Image Source: [Handle Events in Lightning Web Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/handle-events-in-lightning-web-components))

> **Update : Passing event from grand-child to grand-parent**

Lets say we have a LWC component structure as follows.

[image: Component Structure]

We can pass event values between grand-child and grand-parent or the top most root component as follows.

Use `bubbles : true` to pass values up the component hierarchy. And use `composed : true` if you want to expose the event outside the shadow root.

**grandChild.js**

```
const sampleEvent = new CustomEvent('search', { bubbles : true, detail: { foo : 'bar' }, composed : true });
this.dispatchEvent(sampleEvent);
```

**Note:** If an event uses this configuration `bubbles:true` & `composed:true`, the event type becomes part of the component’s public API. It also forces the consuming component and all of its ancestors to include the event as part of their APIs.

This way,  we don't have to handle this event in the parent component , Instead in grand parent we can handle it as follows

**grandParent.html**

```
<c-parent onsearch={handleSearch}></c-parent>
```

**grandParent.js**

```
handleSearch = (event) => {
   console.log(event.detail);
}
```

For more details , refer - [LWC Events Propagation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_propagation)

Comment: Thanks @Jayant. This is where question is, is it not overkill to pass the same event up the hierarchy multiple times to pass some data. It seems very repetitive to me.

Comment: I would agree with you. But it seems there’s no other way (at least known to me) how we can achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @jayant, will keep the question open for few days to see if anyone else can pitch in. Appreciate your answer with links from salesforce but seems overkill  to me.

Comment: Sure. I too will see if I can find any other way.

Answer (score 1):

To bubble an event from a child to a grandparent, set `bubbles: true`. (Use the default value for `compose`, which is `false`.) This configuration bubbles the event up the DOM, but doesn't cross shadow boundaries. The event is visible only in the template that contains your component.

You can see examples in the [LWC Dev Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_propagation) and in the EventBubbling recipe in [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/eventBubbling/eventBubbling.html). I'll walk through some code from the EventBubbling recipe.

The component hierarchy is `c-event-bubbling` -> `lightning-layout-item` -> `c-contact-list-item-bubbling`.

`c-contact-list-item-bubbling` dispatches a custom event called `contactselect` with `bubbles: true`.

The event listener is on its parent, `lightning-layout-item`, and the event is handled in its grandparent, `c-event-bubbling`.

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="EventBubbling" icon-name="standard:logging">
        <template if:true={contacts.data}>
            <lightning-layout class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
                <!-- c-contact-list-item-bubbling emits a bubbling event so a single listener on a containing element works -->
                <lightning-layout-item
                    class="wide"
                    oncontactselect={handleContactSelect}
                >
                    <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                        <c-contact-list-item-bubbling
                            class="slds-show slds-is-relative"
                            key={contact.Id}
                            contact={contact}
                        ></c-contact-list-item-bubbling>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item class="slds-var-m-left_medium">
                    <template if:true={selectedContact}>
                        <img
                            src={selectedContact.Picture__c}
                            alt="Profile photo"
                        />
                        <p>{selectedContact.Name}</p>
                        <p>{selectedContact.Title}</p>
                        <p>
                            <lightning-formatted-phone
                                value={selectedContact.Phone}
                            ></lightning-formatted-phone>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <lightning-formatted-email
                                value={selectedContact.Email}
                            ></lightning-formatted-email>
                        </p>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>
        </template>
        <template if:true={contacts.error}>
            <c-error-panel errors={contacts.error}></c-error-panel>
        </template>
        <c-view-source source="lwc/eventBubbling" slot="footer">
            Child-to-grandparents communication using an event that bubbles and
            is handled on a higher level element in the DOM tree. Click an item
            in the list to see the recipe in action.
        </c-view-source>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this information with caution, as it's really easy to make your application unusable.

### window.dispatchEvent

Instead of dispatching to the component, you can dispatch directly to the window. Typically, I'd recommend only doing this for true "app" level events. Things like toast messages, loading graphics, or theme changes.

You can build some artificial restraints such as a self-imposed api.

```
function AppDispatch(namespace, eventName, data) {
    const event = new CustomEvent(`${namespace}__${eventName}`, { detail: data });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Then you can just add a window event listener to your namespace__eventName. You could add it to your LightningElement extension as a constructor.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export class WindowEvents extends LightningElement {
    events = [];

    watchFor(namespace, eventName, callback) {
        this.events.push([namespace, eventName, callback]);
        window.addEventListener(`${namespace}__${eventName}`, callback);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        for (const event of this.events) {
            window.removeEventListener(`${event[0]}__${event[1]}`, event[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd just import WindowEvents instead of LightningElement in your components. You'd have access to `this.watchFor('loading', 'done', ()=>console.log('done'))` in all components using this class. Be aware of component lifecycles, if you're not deliberate you might want to add a checker in watchFor to prevent multiple identical events.